# Digital Check Device Reset process

Tags: hardware-failure

I am trying to ping a Digital Check device with its IP but It isn't responding. How to reset the settings of this device by any hardware process?
I have followed the manual of digital check setup.

Comment: Please provide more information. What model of device are you using? Do you have a link to the steps the manual suggests? If not, can you tell us the steps you've taken? This question is tagged hardware-failure, how can you be sure that a hardware-failure has occurred?

Comment: When i have installed the device for the first time using below manual link, it worked but the very next day the IP was unable to hit.

https://www.digitalcheck.com/support/hardware/securelink-manual/

Comment: That link is password protected.

Comment: sorry I forget to add the password.
password : sl-dcc630

Comment: By the way i found the solution (If you set a static IP it stops responding on the given device IP).
To reset the digital check device follow the below process.

Please download the link below.  Place the SLU file on a FAT32 USB flash drive.  Unplug power from the SL device, plug in the USB, then plug in the power.  Wait 60 seconds then remove the drive.  This will reset it back to factory defaults, and you should see some log files on the USB drive if it worked.

https://digitalcheck.sharefile.com/d-s3daea857e4b41089

Comment: @timotree thanks for paying attention to my question. :)

Comment: :-) you're welcome. Also, on Super User you're encouraged to post an answer to your own question if you figure it out. Please copy the information that you put into that comment and put it into the answer box below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (If you set a static IP it stops responding on the given device IP). To reset the digital check device follow the below process. Please download the link below. Place the SLU file on a FAT32 USB flash drive. Unplug power from the SL device, plug in the USB, then plug in the power. Wait 60 seconds then remove the drive. This will reset it back to factory defaults, and you should see some log files on the USB drive if it worked. digitalcheck.sharefile.com/d-s3daea857e4b41089